# Differences Between <a> Tags on General Browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) and the Google Search App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, hyperlink

I have a website I have made in Nextjs and React.

On the mobile version of the navbar and homepage, I have two links, one of them is an <a tel=> tag with an SVG icon within it, another one is just an <a sms=> tag.

When tapping these on mobile devices on general browsers (firefox, chrome, safari), the links work just fine.  But when accessing on the general Google search application, the links will not work at all and entail no functionality.  I'm also seeing that this is happening with all links on the site.

How can I make this work on the Google search mobile application as well?

Here is the code, just as general examples with the actual phone number omitted, don't worry, I have it on there normally:

```
<a href="tel:sample_number_here" class="phoneIcon"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="phone" class="svg-inline--fa fa-phone fa-2xl Nav_phone__KUqrZ" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M164.9 24.6c-7.7-18.6-28-28.5-47.4-23.2l-88 24C12.1 30.2 0 46 0 64C0 311.4 200.6 512 448 512c18 0 33.8-12.1 38.6-29.5l24-88c5.3-19.4-4.6-39.7-23.2-47.4l-96-40c-16.3-6.8-35.2-2.1-46.3 11.6L304.7 368C234.3 334.7 177.3 277.7 144 207.3L193.3 167c13.7-11.2 18.4-30 11.6-46.3l-40-96z"></path></svg></a>
```

And

```
<a class="FirstLanding_link__vSmFC" href="sms:number_goes_here">Sample Number Ommitted</a>
```

I know something is wrong, as I can go to a general website on the Google Search app such as NFL and their links/buttons will work, but mine won't , but only in the Google Search app.

By Google app, I mean this:
https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/google/id284815942

Help is greatly appreciated.